# PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR in case of same DB is used for two different projects which are connected with each other in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, deployment, schema.rb

I'm running two projects as a different repository with git. One is admit another one is `Web` in rails, both are connected with each other, Basically same database is used. I only made the migration on admin report and then cloned it into the web. The problem is, I'm deploying it on the server and test cases failed the error says

```
ActionView::Template::Error: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column fees.discount does not exist
```

I just don't understand why it has been happening, in admin I have that field presents.

I think schema.rb may playing role in this case. I'm not so sure about it.

Here is my migration,

```
class AddDiscountToFeel < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
   def change
     add_column :fees, :discount, :integer, default: nil, null: true
   end
 end
```

And here is my Model fields in **development**:

```
 2.3.1 :008 > Fee.column_names
 => ["id", "booth_id", "amount", "description", "created_at", "updated_at", "discount"]
```

And here is my Model fields in **test**:

```
C238s-iMac:web c238$ RAILS_ENV=test rails c 
Loading test environment (Rails 5.0.0.1)
2.3.1 :001 > Fee.column_names
 => ["id", "booth_id", "amount", "description", "created_at", "updated_at", "discount"]
```

And here is my error's snap:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some code ? so we can identify

Comment: Sure, you can see my updated question above- @Vishal Thanks

Comment: I can't check your error's snap, Can you please upload here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I was right

It has been long time in web that I haven’t updated schema from admin that’s why I’ve faced this issue.

**Solution:** Copied `schema.rb` from admin into web repo, because both projects use same DB.

May the answer will helpful for someone also.

Answer (score 0):

Can try to run to add `discount` to the table?

`bundle exec rake db:migrate`

if using heroku:

`heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: Yes, I've ran migration in development as well test environment. Please see my updated question.